# How to merge two text files for accurate OCR like diff

Tags: algorithm, ocr, diff

how can I merge two text files? The end goal is to merge n number of text files.

There is 2 way and n way merge algorithm, but aren’t they for lists and for sorted lists? Not text files?

And I think the Diff tool is related, but diff only produces the differences, doesn’t actually automate the merging.

Thanks.

I created my own algorithm, but it’s complex.

Edit: to answer some question, what I mean is I want to do the equivalent of a diff in Git for example. And instead of doing a manual submission of a merge request, I want a program that automatically merges.

The actual application is that I want to use Tesseract OCR to convert receipts into text. But it makes mistakes. Thus, I want to take 5 pictures of the same receipt, get 5 transcriptions, and then get the average/merged of all 5 texts to get the most accurate output merged text.

Made my own algorithm but complex

Comment: Is your own algorithm delivering the expected result? If yes and only the complexity is the problem, then we need to see your algorithm.